# Google Apps Script: Adding text at a certain position

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, methods

I'm trying to insert a array of text at certain position with google apps script.

For example: In row 2 I need to add the name Mike with city Detroit.
What I tried is appending the row with the data and deleting the row before it. This is a messy solution to my problem.

[image]

Is there a method which can take a rownumber as a parameter and add text to that row?

Comment: Sheet.getRange(row,col).setValue();

Comment: or `my_sheet.getRange('B3:C3').setValues( [ ['Mike', 'Detroit'] ] )`